# Deploying an App from Xcode to a device without launching the app

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to track down an 0x8badf00d error which is caused by the watchdog process killing our app on startup for taking too long.   The problem is that it only happens on the first launch of the app (when the app is creating our database).

So I need to be able to deploy the app from XCode to my IPad without having it autolaunch the app. The only options I see in Xcode are to Build-run or Build-debug.  How do you deploy an app to a device without having Xcode launch it.  I want to do this because I've read that if Xcode starts your app, it disables the watchdog process.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode's **Organzier** (available from the menu: *Window/Organizer*) will allow you to load an app onto a device. You can then run the app without the debugger.

Comment: Thanks, that worked..  I was able to drag the XXX.app file from the Products folder onto the Device in the Organizer and it appeared on the device and wasn't launched.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is available in Xcode, but a workaround would be for you to add code to your app to always force it to go through the initialization codepath on launch.  For instance, if you're being watchdogged while creating your database, add a little code to delete your database as soon as you launch, so you'll always re-create the database.  This should work for your debugging purposes.

Comment: The OP is trying to run *without the debugger attached* to observe the watchdog's behavior. (The watchdog timer doesn't kick-in if you're debugging.) The problem *isn't* forcing the database to re-create.

Comment: Right.  He'll run it once from Xcode to get the app onto the device, then he'll kill the process and run it again by tapping it on the iPhone (rather than running it from Xcode).  When he runs it this second time, it won't be attached to by Xcode, and he'll be able to observe its behavior as if it were the first launch.

Comment: That seems like it would work as well, Thanks Ryan.   I'll go with Jon's answer in this case since it doesn't involve a code change.

Comment: Yes, his is the better answer.  :)