# Xcode Organizer doesn't show my app bundle on the connected iPhone anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, organizer

I used to be able to see my iOS app and access the app bundle from the Organizer window, by selecting my iPhone and selecting Applications.  I would then see my apps listed, along with any other ad-hoc apps.  For some reason, my app dropped off the list, and I can't figure out how to get it back.  I suspect this has to do with having submitted the app to the app store, and a possible change to the signing, and thus the subsequent non-release (debug) versions aren't appearing as being adhoc.  I have screenshots of where I expect to find my app, below.

Can anyone shed some light as to what I need to do to be able to access my app bundle again?  I also suspect that this is the same reason I can no longer use Instruments to performance test my app.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple DTS responded to my bug report.  I had to reinstall Xcode and then I could access my app bundle again.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and in my case the app showed up again when, after manually deleting it from my device, I clicked the Add button under Organizer->Devices->My Device->Applications (where the app should have been displaying already) and dragged my app from under the Products folder in to the Finder dialog; a process described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109055/deploying-an-app-from-xcode-to-a-device-without-launching-the-app). After a pause with no indication of any progress the app was again displayed in the Organizer window.

Comment: Actually just deleting the app and install it again solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -2):

The circle on the left of your device name is gray (zPad). An update may have removed the development usage for this device.
Click on the device, you may have a button on the right side "use for development". Just click it, and it must be OK :

[image: use-for-development]

Comment: That iPad just got a newer version of iOS, prior to experiencing these issues. The iPhone above, which has a green indicator, is also having the same issue.   Let's solve for the iPhone for now.

Comment: Try quitting iTunes and re-plug your device, I was having a similar issue when iTunes was running... not investigated anymore because it worked.

Comment: This has been going on for weeks.  Many restarts in the meantime.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the device from the organizer, and then re-use it for dev ?